# Plotting a 1x1 contingency table returns "Error in rep.int(0, ydim) : invalid 'times' value"

Tags: r

Plotting a 1-by-1 contingency table returns an error:

```
dat <- read.table(textConnection('
foo bar
TRUE TRUE
TRUE TRUE
'), header = TRUE, colClasses=c('logical', 'logical'))
mosaicplot(table(dat))

Error in rep.int(0, ydim) : invalid 'times' value
```

**Why?**

---

Follow-up question: [How to plot a mosaicplot for a 1x1 contingeny table?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62243596/12635841)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There appears to be too less variation in your data, if you set one element to `FALSE` it will work.

**Reason:** Method `graphics:::mosaicplot.default` contains the following lines (e.g. lines 12 and 13),

```
xdim <- maxdim[1L]
XP <- rep.int(0, xdim)
```

and `maxdim` seems to become `numeric(0)` probably due to one-dimensionality of your data:

```
ydim <- numeric(0)
rep.int(0, ydim)
# Error in rep.int(0, numeric(0)) : invalid 'times' value
```