# How to plot a mosaicplot for a 1x1 contingency table?

Tags: r, plot, mosaic-plot

Plotting a 1-by-1 contingency table returns an error:

```
dat <- read.table(textConnection('
foo bar
TRUE TRUE
TRUE TRUE
'), header = TRUE, colClasses=c('logical', 'logical'))
mosaicplot(table(dat))

Error in rep.int(0, ydim) : invalid 'times' value
```

[As I learned](https://stackoverflow.com/q/62242642/12635841), the code in the mosaicplot function doesn't allow to plot a 1-by-1-table. But then, **how *do* I plot a mosaicplot of that table?**

---

*Background.*

I am plotting a series of dynamically created tables, some of which sometimes happen to have only one column and one row, at other times they have more dimensions. Having an undivided rectangle in that series of mosaicplots is valuable information and easily grasped in that visual representation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One possibility is to coerce the variables to be plotted to `factor` and specify the possible outcomes in `levels` (in the desired order). Then zero count cells will be represented as thin lines.

```
dat[] = lapply(dat, factor, levels = c(TRUE, FALSE))
mosaicplot(table(dat))
```

[image]

Comment: For the second solution (coercing to factor), removing spacing between the tiles results in an almost pretty plot: `mosaicplot(table(dat), off = 0)`.

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the thin lines of *@Henrik*'s (*great!*) solution you could substitute one-dimensional cases with a custom plot function.

```
mpOneDim <- function(tbl, title="table(dat)") {
  dn <- attr(tbl, "dimnames")
  labs <- names(dn)
  levels <- unlist(dn)
  plot.new()
  rect(0.0125, -.035, .985, .99, col="gray", border=1)
  mtext(title, line=1.55, font=2, cex=1.2)
  mtext(labs[1], 1, 1)
  mtext(labs[2], 2, 1)
  mtext(levels[2], 2, -1.15, cex=.7)
  mtext(levels[2], 3, -.75, cex=.7)
}
mpOneDim(table(dat))
```

[image]

In your function do something like this:

```
if (sum(dim(table(dat))) <= 2) {
  mpOneDim(table(dat))
} else {
  mosaicplot(table(dat))
}
```

---

*Data:*

```
dat <- structure(list(foo = c(TRUE, TRUE), bar = c(TRUE, TRUE)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```